# Number of Ionization event estimation

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, gas, scattering-cross-section, laser-interaction

First of all, I am new in this field and therefore if I ask a silly question please forgive me.
I have a gas-cell (say 3$\times$3$\times$3 mm$^3$ volume) filled with a N$_2$ gas. The number density is known. Now I want to shine a pulsed laser light on this volume element (gas cell) with 20ns, 800nm, and energy per pulse 100 mJ. Now with a known cross-section how do I calculate the number of ionized N$_2$ per pulse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it will take a fairly high order multi-photon event to ionize, I’d say the answer is really close to zero. Having slung higher energy (and power), shorter wavelength beams around in air, you get no ionization.

Comment: Can you please suggest to me the mathematical way to estimate the number if we have a shorter wavelength and higher power.

Comment: Papers like https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3646478 might be a place to start - but there they talk about multi-photon ionization of argon in N2, with the excited Ar leading to population of excited states in the N2 molecules, ionization of N2 to begin with. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037596017290309X talks of using doubled YAG and needing TW/cm2 of power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single photon scattering/absorption event with a cross section ${\sigma}$, which is $[L^2]$, or an area, the number of scattering events per pulse is:

$$ N = N_{\gamma}\rho_A\sigma $$

Here

$$N_{\gamma} = \frac E {\hbar\omega}$$

is the number of photons in a pulse, and

$$\rho_A = \rho_{N_2}\times L$$

is the areal density ($[L^{-2}]$) of target molecules. $ \rho_{N_2}$ is the *number* density of molecules and $L$ is the length of the target chamber.